# UIView hitTest:withEvent: calls come in threes

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with no subviews.  When I drag the scroll view, its `hitTest:withEvent:` gets called three times, and there are never any touches in the event.  Why is that (I saw another post but it doesn't seem to have a consclusion)?  Here is the log of the scroll view's `hitTest...` and `pointInside:withEvent:`

```
2011-05-11 20:12:37.472 MyApp[10909:707] hit test for UIScrollView 119.500000,102.000000, timestamp: 357978 touches: {()}
2011-05-11 20:12:37.475 MyApp[10909:707] pointInside for UIScrollView 119.500000,102.000000,  timestamp: 357978 touches: {()} 
2011-05-11 20:12:37.477 MyApp[10909:707] hit test for UIScrollView 119.500000,102.000000, timestamp: 357978 touches: {()}
2011-05-11 20:12:37.479 MyApp[10909:707] pointInside for UIScrollView 119.500000,102.000000,  timestamp: 357978 touches: {()} 
2011-05-11 20:12:37.481 MyApp[10909:707] hit test for UIScrollView 119.500000,102.000000, timestamp: 358021 touches: {()}
2011-05-11 20:12:37.482 MyApp[10909:707] pointInside for UIScrollView 119.500000,102.000000,  timestamp: 358021 touches: {()} 
2011-05-11 20:12:37.484 MyApp[10909:707] pointInside for UIScrollView 119.500000,396.000000,  timestamp: 358021 touches: {()}
```

Comment: I found the exact same thing myself in a custom UIView subclass. I have overridden the hitTest:withEvent: method to do some custom processing and thought the multiple calls were down to some bad code, but reading here it seems to be a quirk of iOS's event handling. Would be interested to find out why three calls are necessary.

Comment: Not sure if this is an answer, so I will post it here...assuming your heirachy is this: UIWindow --> UIViewController's UIView --> UIScrollView, is it possible that you're getting a hit test for each "hittable" view in the hierarchy? The documentation states that pointInside is called down the hierarchy. Add a UIView under your scroll view and see if you get it called 4 times. The other idea is that it gives you 3 so you can take an average.

Answer (score 10):

`hitTest:` is a utility method designed to find a view at a specific point. It **DOES NOT** represent a user tapping on the touch screen. It is totally sensible for hitTest to be called several times in response to the same event; all the method is supposed to do is return the view under the point and it **SHOULD NOT** trigger any side effects.

If you want to track touch events, you should override `touchesBegan:` and friends.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and didn't actually find an answer to this, but you could use one of these 2 solutions:

1.
Store the hit tests in an array and compare them so you can return when it's the same to prevent it getting called 3 times in a row.

2.
Instead of hittest, use touchesBegan, touchesCancelled, touchesEnded and touchesMoved like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch * touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:touch.view];
    NSLog(@"%f - %f", touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
}
```

I used the touchesBegan, etc solution and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure why, but here are some further insights into this question:

- It doesn't seem to be specific to UIScrollView.  I ran a test with a UIView - same results.
- It seems to get called three times on the root view regardless of the view hierarchy or the return value.
- The event passed to hitTest is basically blank for the first two calls (but the point is always valid); the event has a valid timestamp but no touch information for the third call.
- It looks like `UIResponder` methods aren't called until *after* all three hitTest calls complete.  For example, touchesBegan:withEvent: won't be called until the end.
- All three calls originate from different points in the (closed-source, I believe) function UIApplicationHandleEvent, based on stack traces.

My best guess is that, in some cases, the return value from `hitTest` might change between calls.  I cannot think of why this might happen, though.  If this isn't true, then it doesn't make sense to call it multiple times.

Another idea is that the code is simply inefficiently-written.  This seems less likely, but based on this information, it is a possibility.

Comment: I set up a project with a scroll view sitting in the VC's view, and performed a hit test of a random point in viewDidAppear. I only get 1 call. Where are you calling hitTest?

Comment: Also tried intercepting events on the UIWindow and removing/breaking the responder chain etc. I'm still puzzled! :)